# I need two functions to get CPU Load and Memory load In PHP

Tags: php

HI 
I need a function to cpu load ( percentage )
and another function to get Memory load
In PHP

Answer (score 1):

If you use linux, you can retrieve it from shell.

Edit: [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 1):

[`memory_get_usage()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

> ```
> int memory_get_usage  ([ bool $real_usage= false  ] )
> ```
>
> Returns the amount of memory, in
> bytes, that's currently being
> allocated to your PHP script.

I'm not sure there's a simple, portable way of measuring CPU load.  Are you on Linux?